# How to take 'password' like input in C++ from terminal?

Tags: c++, c++11, input, terminal, passwords

When the user types password on a terminal, it should not be displayed (or something like ******* should be displayed). How do I achieve this?

In `bash` passwords can be inputed in this way-

```
#!/bin/bash
# Read Password
echo -n Password: 
read -s password
```

Is it possible to do in c++?

I am on Linux, want to know Linux and windows solution both.

Comment: In C++ you can't. There's no way to do it in standard C++. You have to use operating-system dependent functions or libraries, and since you haven't told us what OS you're targeting we can't help you further.

Comment: I am on Linux, want to know Linux and windows solution both.

Comment: On linux, start with "man stty, termios, tcstattr"...